# Setting the indicator of a custom toolbar to an SVG image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to set the indicator of a custom toolbar to an SVG image. The indicator gets successfully replaced, but the icon isn't positioned well.

[image: Here is what it looks like now]
This is how the icon is positioned now, but I want it to have a top and left margin, or ideally to position itself at the vertical center with a slight margin to the left.

Here is the image drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:height="64dp"
   android:width="64dp"
   android:viewportHeight="48"
   android:viewportWidth="48" >
 <group>
   <path
        android:fillColor="@null"
        android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
   <path
        android:fillColor="@color/white"
        android:pathData="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z" />
 </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed the issue. I only had to play a bit with the size & viewportsize and now the icon is perfectly aligned.